# Json filed not dumping data into text file I created

Tags: python, json, windows, file, dictionary

What I'm trying to do is basically make a user input and jump into a text file with JSON.

```
    user = ''
    RepQues = {}
    while(user.lower() != "quit"):
        user  = str(input("Type here:"))
        RepQues[user] = user
        if user in RepQues:
            pass
        else:
            RepQues[user] = user
            with open('Texts.txt', 'a') as file:
                json.dump({user: user}, file)
    
    with open('Texts.txt', 'r') as file:
        print(file.read())
```

It's not working though, and I'm not getting any errors either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why will the else condition be executed?

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish, new properties go to the else statement. Duplicate values go to the if node bro

Comment: I fixed the problem. I just had to make the text file into a Json, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is always true.

With the statement on line 5 (`RepQues[user] = user`), you're inserting the input into your dictionary immediately.

Then on line 6, you're asking if the same value is in the dictionary (`if user in RepQues:`) - which will always be true. It is dutifully executing the instruction in the `if` block and passing.

Remove line five.